# file upload in google cloud store using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

i am trying to upload a file to Google cloud store using Google app engine. I found this one to upload a file to GCS. In these some hidden fields value are known. But i cant able to figure out what is siganture, privacy and GoogleAccessId. Please help me the process to prepare all these values. I have read the document but cant able to understand and preparing.

I am new to topic.

```
<form action="https://******storage.googleapis.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="****" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/png" />
    <input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="**********" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="********" />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" value="201" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: You might missed that in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs